# Create flag field in Laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

### Table structure

**users:** `id, username`

**items:** `id, name`

**inventories:** `id, user_id, item_id`

---

I have a list of ALL items in a 5x5 grid on a page.

I want to be able to show a **[+]** icon if the user doesn't already have the item in `inventories` and a **[-]** icon if the user already has the item in `inventories`. I'm trying to think of the most efficient way to achieve this.

In Laravel, if I left outer join all records, is there a way to create and set a flag field `in_inventory = 'Y|N'`?

In my view, I want to be able to have something like this:

```
@foreach ($items as $item)
    {{ $item->name }}<br>
    @if ($item->in_inventory == 'Y')
        <a href="#">[-]</a>
    @else
        <a href="#">[+]</a>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: What does your current query look like? If your doing a `LEFT JOIN` you could use something like  `SELECT users.*, items.*, IF( inventories.id IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) AS in_inventory` to your logic to get a flag for which items are in the users inventory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating SQL that only selected the id, then checked if it was `in_array()` to display.